# let vs let* in LISP - is there a difference in efficiency?

Tags: lisp

This should be a quick one: I've been asking myself often whether there's a difference in efficiency between the LISP special functions `let` and `let*`? For instance, are they equivalent when creating only one variable?

Answer (score 4):

As Barmar pointed out, there shouldn't be any performance difference in "production ready" Lisps.

For CLISP, both of these produce the same (bytecode) assembly:

```
(defun foo (x) (let ((a x) (b (* x 2))) (+ a b)))
(defun bar (x) (let* ((a x) (b (* x 2))) (+ a b)))
```

Though for non-optimizing, simple interpreters (or also compilers) there could very well be a difference, e.g. because `let*` and `let` could be implemented as simple macros, and a single lambda with multiple parameters is probably more efficient than multiple lambdas with a single parameter each:

```
;; Possible macro expansion for foo's body
(funcall #'(lambda (a b) (+ a b)) x (* x 2))
;; Possible macro expansion for bar's body
(funcall #'(lambda (a) (funcall #'(lambda (b) (+ a b)) (* x 2))) x)
```

Having multiple lambdas, as well as the (avoidable) closing over `a` could make the second expansion less "efficient".

When used with only one binding, then there shouldn't be any difference even then, though.

But if you're using an implementation that isn't optimizing `let*` (or `let`), then there's probably no point discussing performance at all.

Comment: I cannot see any documentation in the hyperspec requiring optimizing redundantly used `let*` to `let` so even if all the current lisps make identical compiled code it still would be a de facto standard just like you really cannot assume tail call optimization.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any performance difference. The only difference between them is the scope of the variables, which is dealt with at compile time. If there's only one variable, there's absolutely no difference.